# What does "v1/se" stands for in WEB APIs?

Tags: api, rest, url, openapi, webapi

Many Web URLs contains "v1/se" string in them. OK for "v1", that is the version... But, what about "se"?

Comment: Maybe Swedish server or maybe services when docs has the v1/docs endpoints. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Your second hypothesis could be the answer I was looking for! I inherited a project in which the base URLs of different microservices start with 'v1/se'. It is not a Swedish project. So I think it makes a lot of sense that "se" stands for "services".